# Spring data JPA/Hibernate SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000 with Native query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have this spring data native query which works well in MySql

```
@Query(value = "SELECT profile.*, COUNT(post.id) AS post_count " +
            "    FROM profile " +
            "    LEFT JOIN post  " +
            "    ON profile.id = post.profile_id " +
            "    where profile.id not in ?1 " +
            "    AND (profile.country = ?2  OR profile.langue = ?3) " +
            "    GROUP BY profile.id " +
            "    ORDER BY post_count desc ", nativeQuery = true)
```

In my app with spring boot i have this error :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from post) AS post_count     FROM profile     LEFT JOIN post      ON pr' at line 1
```

I displayed the queries with this
`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true`

I got this :

```
Hibernate: 
    /* dynamic native SQL query */ SELECT
        profile.*,
        COUNT(post.id) AS post_count     
    FROM
        profile     
    LEFT JOIN
        post      
            ON profile.id = post.profile_id     
    where
        profile.id not in (
            ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
        )     
        AND (
            profile.country = ?  
            OR profile.langue = ?
        )     
    GROUP BY
        profile.id     
    ORDER BY
        post_count desc  limit ?


Hibernate: 
    /* dynamic native SQL query */ select
        count(
    LEFT) FROM
        profile     
    LEFT JOIN
        post      
            ON profile.id = post.profile_id     
    where
        profile.id not in (
            ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
        )     
        AND (
            profile.country = ?  
            OR profile.langue = ?
        )     
    GROUP BY
        profile.id
```

I think is the problem is in the second query : **count(
LEFT) FROM ..**
But i don't know how to solve this..

Any idea please ?

Comment: Is `LEFT` a column in your table ? What do you mean by `select count(LEFT)` ? LEFT is [MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)  and if it is a column name (which is a bad idea) should be in backticks

Comment: NO ! i don't have any 'LEFT' property in my database..
This is the sql prrinted with spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true